# How i do update an existing contact phone number?

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

Hello everyone I am trying to update a contact's phone using the following code

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFErrorRef error = nil;
    ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    bool didAddphone = ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneMultiValue, (CFTypeRef)(_homePhoneText.text), kABHomeLabel, NULL);

if(didAddphone){
        ABRecordSetValue(ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, [_ID integerValue]),
                         kABPersonPhoneProperty,
                         phoneMultiValue,
                         nil);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error adding email: %@", error);
        error = nil;
    }
```

But its not working. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: `ABAddressBookCreate` is deprecated and will not work under iOS 6 (it always returns NULL). Instead use `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions` (documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html ).

After that, you need to save the address book to make the changes stick around, do that by calling `ABAddressBookSave` with your address book.

Comment: Hello ok i am now using :
 CFErrorRef error = nil;
     ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
   

Can you tell me how to add ABAddressBookSave?

Comment: kool great it works!!  ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);